# send data from client (vanilla js) to .net core API

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, api, axios

vanilla javascript client (I tried doing it with axios/ajax/fetch)

```
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
debugger;
var name = document.getElementById("errorInput").value;
var description = document.getElementById("errorDescriptionInput").value;
var date = document.getElementById("errorDateInput").value;
var mail = document.getElementById("senderEmailInput").value;
var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('fileInput', file);

const error = {
    ErrorName: name,
    ErrorDescription: description,
    ErrorSubmittedDate: date,
    SenderEmail: mail,
    Documents: formData,
}

axios.post("https://localhost:44310/api/Error/senderror","sendFile", error, {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
})
})
```

.net controller API

```
[EnableCors("policy")]
[HttpPost]
[Route("senderror")]
public async Task<IActionResult> HandleError([FromForm]ErrorModel error)
{
   return Ok();
}
```

Browser debugger shows that the model contains the values, but the data that comes to the controller is null.
Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I believe the problem is with content type, you can not have the same property with two values either "multipart/form-data" or "application/json". You should try removing "Content-Type": "application/json".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are sending your file in formdata inside your error object and on api you have applied

```
[FromForm]
```

so server expect the data in form and you are sending an object containing formdata. i think if you append all data in formdata then it would work coz you api is expecting data in formdata.change it like this

```
const myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
debugger;
var name = document.getElementById("errorInput").value;
var description = document.getElementById("errorDescriptionInput").value;
var date = document.getElementById("errorDateInput").value;
var mail = document.getElementById("senderEmailInput").value;
var file = document.getElementById('fileInput').files[0];

var formData = new FormData();
error.append('ErrorName', name);
error.append('ErrorDescription', description);
error.append('ErrorSubmittedDate', date);
error.append('SenderEmail', file);
error.append('Documents', mail);


axios.post("https://localhost:44310/api/Error/senderror","sendFile", error, {
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
})
})
```

you have to set

```
"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!